# Set UIView Border Color or width in swift using @IBInspectable

Tags: swift, uiview, ibinspectable

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }
}

  @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
```

By using this code i can set the border color or width of UIView. But i want to set the individual borders like(Top, Bottom, left or right) color or width by using @IBInspectable. How can i do this?